# How to play youtube data api video in landscape fullscreen mode by default

Tags: android, video, youtube, fullscreen, landscape

I am developing an android app, where I want to make a collection of some youtube videos. I want to play these videos in fullscreen landscape mode when I tap on any of the videos. Please help me. Here is the code

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.pss.hotbellydance;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
public static final String KEY = "AIzaSyDUbG4mpT9FCLhkVi3uRdI1G-Dt9DRXTlU";
public static final String VID_ID = "UVSTNzonj8Q";
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.video1);

    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VID_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    youTubePlayerView.initialize(KEY,onInitializedListener);
}
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.pss.hotbellydance.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
android:id="@+id/video1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp">
</com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your youtube activity in landscape mode:

```
<activity  android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Or programatically:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: this code converts the full app in landscape mode. I want only to play the videos in landscape and full screen mode.